# How do I return values in lua function after calling other lua function inside C function

Tags: c++, c, lua, callback, stack

So i have something like this:

```
public static int Window(ILuaState lua)
{
    int id = lua.L_CheckInteger(1);
    Rect rect = RectLib.CheckRect(lua, 2);
    string title = lua.L_CheckString(3);
    int fRef = lua.L_Ref(LuaDef.LUA_REGISTRYINDEX); // a function was passed as a parameter

    Rect r = GUI.Window(id, rect, (i) => // this functions executes before RectLib.PushRect right here
    {
        lua.RawGetI(LuaDef.LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, fRef);
        lua.PushInteger(i);
        if (lua.PCall(1, 0, 0) != ThreadStatus.LUA_OK)
            Debug.LogError(lua.ToString(-1));
    }, title);

    RectLib.PushRect(lua, r); // basically pushes a table 

    return 0;
}
```

The problem here that after calling function that was passed as a parameter something bad goes with the stack and return value becomes `nil`. I tried putting `lua.Pop(1)`, `lua.Pop(2)`, `lua.Pop(3)` after `lua.PCall` but i failed. What do i do?

The stack after looks like this:

```
5: none
4: table
3: string (string title)
2: table
1: number (int id)
0: number (4th element of a table that need to be returned)
-1: table
-2: string (string title)
-3: table
-4: number
-5: function
```

Help

Comment: And what do you want to return from this function?  You should push these values to the stack and replace `return 0;` with returning integer number = number of returned values.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff omg thanks i didnt see that `return 0` somehow, thanks a lot